# Get XML output from SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing SQL query to get output as below . I am not using any tables from database.
A query to get the desired output as

```
<Property ID="0" Name="Color" NumOfItems="11">
    <Item ID="0" Name="D"/>
    <Item ID="1" Name="E"/>
    <Item ID="2" Name="F"/>
    <Item ID="3" Name="G"/>
    <Item ID="4" Name="H"/>
    <Item ID="5" Name="I"/>
    <Item ID="6" Name="J"/>
    <Item ID="7" Name="K"/>
    <Item ID="8" Name="L"/>
    <Item ID="9" Name="M"/>
    <Item ID="10" Name="N"/>
  </Property>
```

I tried as this

```
      SELECT 
   (
     SELECT '0' AS 'Item/@ID','D' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '1' AS 'Item/@ID','E' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '2' AS 'Item/@ID','F' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '3' AS 'Item/@ID','G' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '4' AS 'Item/@ID','H' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '5' AS 'Item/@ID','I' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '6' AS 'Item/@ID','J' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '7' AS 'Item/@ID','K' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '8' AS 'Item/@ID','L' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '9' AS 'Item/@ID','M' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ),
     (SELECT '10' AS 'Item/@ID','N' AS 'Item/@Name'  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE )
 FOR XML PATH(''),
 ROOT('Property'),TYPE
```

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the fine manual? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> I am not using any tables from database

Well just `SELECT` it...

```
SELECT CAST ('<Property ID="0" Name="Color" NumOfItems="11">
    <Item ID="0" Name="D"/>
    <Item ID="1" Name="E"/>
    <Item ID="2" Name="F"/>
    <Item ID="3" Name="G"/>
    <Item ID="4" Name="H"/>
    <Item ID="5" Name="I"/>
    <Item ID="6" Name="J"/>
    <Item ID="7" Name="K"/>
    <Item ID="8" Name="L"/>
    <Item ID="9" Name="M"/>
    <Item ID="10" Name="N"/>
  </Property>' AS XML)
```

Comment: I have been doing this.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES (0, 'Color', 11)) Property(ID, Name, NumOfItems)
JOIN    (VALUES (0,0,'D'), (0,1,'E'), (0,2,'F')) Item(PropertyID,ID,Name) 
ON      Property.ID = Item.PropertyID
FOR XML AUTO
```

Output:

```
<Property ID="0" Name="Color" NumOfItems="11">
  <Item PropertyID="0" ID="0" Name="D" />
  <Item PropertyID="0" ID="1" Name="E" />
  <Item PropertyID="0" ID="2" Name="F" />
</Property>
```

2)

```
SELECT  *,
        (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0,'D'), (1, 'E'), (2, 'F')) MamboJambo("@ID", "@Name") FOR XML PATH('Item'),TYPE) 
FROM    (VALUES (0,'Color',11)) CocoJambo("@ID", "@Name", "@NumOfItems") 
FOR XML PATH('Property')
```

3)

```
SELECT  CONVERT(XML, N'<Property ID="0" Name="Color" NumOfItems="11">
    <Item ID="0" Name="D"/>
    <Item ID="1" Name="E"/>
    <Item ID="2" Name="F"/>
  </Property>').query(N'
    for $x in (/Property)
    return 
        <Property ID="{$x/@ID}" Name="{$x/@Name}" NumOfItems="{$x/@NumOfItems}" >
        {for $y in ($x/Item) return $y}
        </Property>
');
```